# adding an element to multidimensional array when within foreach loop (PHP)

Tags: php, foreach, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to check if a certain category is allready selected by looping through an array of categories also I want to add another element to the array whci is just a bit to indicate is the category selcated

my categories array looks like this

```
0=>array(category_id=>12,category_name=>"blogger")  
1=>array(category_id=>13,category_name=>"dancer")
```

etc...
now the code i'm trying goes like that:

```
foreach ($userCategories as $key=>$category) {
    if($category['category_id'] == $mediaDetails['currentCategory']) {
        $category['current'] = 1;
    } else {
        $category['current'] = 0;
    }
}
```

when executing

```
die(var_dump($userCategories));
```

I expect to get an array similar to

```
0=>array(category_id=>12,category_name=>"blogger",current=>0)  
1=>array(category_id=>13,category_name=>"dancer",current=>1)
```

but instead I get the same array I had before the foreach loop

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like `$category` is not getting passed by reference.

Try `$userCategories[$key]['current']=1` instead, and see how that works.

Comment: Or fix the foreach `foreach ($userCategories as $key=>&$category) {` (note the &)

Comment: Right; I thought of that but wasn't positive that it would work properly in a foreach.

Comment: I thought that using the ampersand was deprecated? but I did a little test, but I didn't get any warnings
http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: I think `&` is only deprecated when you try to pass an argument as a reference when the function originally does not pass the argument as a reference.